# Disable hotkeys on a specific website

Tags: youtube, keyboard-shortcuts

On YouTube it is very frustarting that they override basically every system level hot key. I.e. <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> to go to the search bar, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1 to 6</kbd> to switch tabs etc.

Is there anyway I could use Greasemonkey to disable these actions?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the YouTube shortcuts you mention are only active whilst the video itself has focus. So you can simply click off the video element, on another part of the page, to effectively disable the keyboard shortcuts. These shortcuts would seem to be part of the Flash player, not the HTML page.

I don't think there is any other, more permanent, way of disabling these shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

How about signing up for html5 on Youtube, this way you don't need Flash and you might get the short cuts back. On Windows 7, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1 ...n</kbd> do work with HTML5 on YouTube, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> does not high light the search bar...

Comment: I signed up to HTML5 on YouTube ages ago - and I'm sure it did display as such back then. However, these days all videos appear to show using the Flash Player (in latest Google Chrome browser) and I do not see any option to switch?!

Comment: It works in my case, even though I had to re-sign up to get it activated. I completely removed Flash, so it has to work with HTML5. If this doesn't work, use `UA Spoofer` from the chrome store and set your browser ID for "www.youtube.com" to "iPad".